# Existence of partial derivative and their continuity in a neighbourhood of a point where it is differentiable

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at some $a \in \mathbb R^2$ , there is it necessarily true that there is a neighbourhood of $a$ in which all the partial derivatives of $f$ exists and they are continuous at $a$ ?

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x) = \|x\|^2 1_{\mathbb{Q}^2} (x) $. Then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Since $f$ is not continuous on any line passing through any $x\neq 0$, the partials cannot exist anywhere except at $x=0$.

Comment: Hi Copper, could you elaborate a bit? How is it differentiable?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: It is only differentiable at $x=0$, any function that satisfes $|f(x)| \le C \|x\|^p$ for $p >1$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with derivative $0$. It follows directly from the definition of the (Frechet) derivative: $|f(x)-f(0) - 0.x | \le \|x\|^{p-1} \|x\|$.